# Syncing Angular routes with predefined server side routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-router

am fairly new to Angular and ive been it learning for the past few days but ive come to a stand still. On my node js server i have code like this:

```
     app.get('/account/dashboard', (req, res) => {
        res.render('dashboard_angular'):
     }
```

when i access the route, the browser url bar looks like this

```
       localhost:3000/account/dashboard
```

and after a second the angular router kicks in and changes it to

```
       localhost:3000/#/
```

click on the url bar and trying to access a route from there can either throw a 404 error or take me back to the home route. Please is there a work around for this? so i can have the url like this

```
        localhost:3000/account/dashboard/#/
```

In react-router@3.1.0, routing works fine even with node js routing, am trying to achieve the same thing in angular
Sorry about my writing, am neither british nor american.

Comment: you will have to modify the base path in angular, and also tell express not to mess when anglar is handling the routes (for example if you do `/account/dashboard/angular-route`) => `app.get('/account/dashboard/*',`

Comment: You should research better ways to serve an angular app other than keeping a synced list of all app routes on your server. That’s error prone and pointless redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. I changed the

```
    <base href="/" />
```

to my current server route which was like

```
    <base href="/account/dashboard/" />
```

and boom problem solved, no more E404 from my node js server

Comment: but that's a fixed route, what if you need to go to /account/configuration? or another route like /admin/dashboard

Comment: @B.J. A.A because am using node js for my routing, anything under /account/dashboard (Dashboard), takes my to the root index of my angular app, any other route above that base route would take me else where INSIDE my node server. So in your case, i would use this route 

          /account/dashboard/configurations